# Can 2 kids in the same house play Minecraft at the same time with 1 licence?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am getting conflicting answers to my question.

We just purchased Minecraft Windows 10 (April 2020) for my son.  However, my daughter wants to play too at the same time and go into a realm to play with her brother.  Playing on 2 separate computers in the same household.  How can we do this without having to purchase another game license?

Some of my search suggests that this can be done without having to purchase another license, I just need to create a new account for her.  If so, what type of an account?  A Microsoft account or a Minecraft account?  And then how do we link it to the original purchase?  Note, we did not create a Minecraft account when we purchased the game.  We purchased it from Microsoft and downloaded it from there.

If the above is NOT possible and I do have to buy another game, then what about this...can I link the ipad Pocket Edition to the Windows 10 game so that my daughter can play on the ipad with her brother on the computer?  I purchased the iPad version as well.  They just don't like it as much.

Comment: You're essentially asking how to violate the EULA and crack the protection. The Minecraft EULA is very lax and allows quite a bit more than other games, allowing multiple installations, playing with the same account in single player from multiple computers simultaneously, and more -  but it draws a line at playing online with the same account from multiple computers simultaneously. This is the point where you're supposed to purchase a second license for the second kid.

Comment: I personally don't think it goes against EULA. But for sure, its 1 account, 1 player. Would not make sense that 1 account could connect to a server multiple times at the same time. Asker will have to buy multiple licenses for his children.

Answer (score 4):

If you're playing on PC, it depends on which version you are using. For Java Win/Mac/Linux): **no; Each named player needs a seperate login as your license is tied to your login/Microsoft Account**. If the same user tries to connect to the same server, the previous connection will get kicked (Source: Have multiple accounts).

However, for Bedrock (Windows Store) edition, **yes; you can install the game in multiple places using a single purchased license** like with the app store (see below), but when you launch the game, each user needs to have their own separate Microsoft account. Otherwise a user conflict happens like in Java and the previous connection is kicked. Unlike Java Edition, accounts used to log into the game (seperate to the one downloading/installing it) do not need to own the game.*

If you're playing on mobile (Android + iOS), then **yes; You can install the app on multiple devices having purchased it once by reusing the same Google Account/Apple ID**, unless they're both on different platforms, then you'll need a copy per platform. Each person just needs their own individual Xbox Account and device (you can't split screen).

If you're playing on console (Nintendo Switch, PlayStation, Xbox, etc.) then **no, you'll need a cartridge/license/account AND console per player, unless playing split-screen**.

*Entitlements and subscriptions such as DLC (Marketplace) and Realms are per-account, though the account that installed the app is usally the payment instrument (who gets charged), especially for the case of Android/iOS and carry along with you regardless of whether you're playing on the Windows/Mobile/Console versions of Bedrock; just log into the same user (may not neceesarily be the one used to download the app) account.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need help, but you would need another PC for this. You can sign into the Microsoft account you purchased the Minecraft with, then install it on there.